# Error: Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: ajax, cors

I am getting this error in Chrome when trying to send an ajax request:

```
Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers
```

Everything works fine in Firefox.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

I solved the problem adding to Apache Web Server virtual host configuration the following settings

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
```

Comment: I had the same problem. If you are using Django , use CORS HEADERS module, Check this CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS - https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/

Comment: @GiulioRoggero : I know I should not ask this here, but still after adding header to response, I am getting the same issue.

Comment: Can u please which file i should add these 2 lines? i had set this in .htaccess file og Magento and still i get preflight error msg!!

Comment: @SachinS this is apache.conf file

Answer (score 17):

Solution for PHP:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
```

(Need to send that before any other content)

Comment: This information was spot on, below is my 'complete' code for the solution.

`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');

echo $_GET['callback'].json_encode($data);`

Answer (score 5):

Set up CORS (Cross-site HTTP Requests) in node. For me it looks like the following:

```
app.use('/api', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type');
  next();
});
```

Comment: Could you please suggest on how to fix this issue in Angular 2: After following all the posts i still face: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400

Answer (score 4):

for nginx

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:59100;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    # proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    # proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;

    # Simple requests
    if ($request_method ~* "(GET|POST)") {
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  *;
    }

    # Preflighted requests
    if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  *;
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD";
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
    }

    # proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    # add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    # add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers Content-Type;
}
```

see
https://distinctplace.com/2017/04/17/nginx-access-control-allow-origin-cors/

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it by adding the following header:
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type

Comment: To what did you add this header to? To the request that you originated in the client side?

Comment: Cant speak for @Van Coding, but to get this to work you should add this header to the http response.

Answer (score 0):

To me with PHP, localy works even if i set only this header setting:

`header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');`